# How do I access coins purchased at ZipZap using a moneygram?

Tags: client, bitinstant

I used a moneygram to purchase some Bitcoins.  Using the information I  got from ZipZap, I was able to get the address where the money was sent and through block explorer that it is there.  I have the ScriptPubKey that contains (I hope) what I need to do to get the coins.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how to get at it.  I have very little knowledge of programming or coding.  How can I release this information without going back to college?

Comment: I should have told you that I do know quite a bit of information, through bitcoin block explorer, about the transaction

Comment: To spend the coins you need the private key, but you usually have a client to take care of that for you. Could you be a bit more specific? I assume that you gave the Bitcoin provider an address you generated with a client. If you tell which program you use, it would be easier to give you some hints.

Comment: What do you mean by 'release the information'? Are you trying to spend the coins? What do you mean by 'going back to college'?

Comment: No, no address given.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was told that the Script portion of the ScriptPubKey held the key for redemption. Back to collegesimply means that I am WAY to old (67) to start learning C++ or whatever.

Comment: I forgot what a joy it is to talk with science people.  After my first couple of For Dummies books I lectured all over the place to audiences full of MCSE's.  Brings back memories.

Comment: I'l edit the title of this question so you'll have a better chance of getting an accurate answer.

Comment: How did you get the "ScriptPubKey" as you describe it?

Answer (score 2):

If you purchased coins you probably gave them an "address" to send it to.  Although "address" is the preferred terminology it can be called a ScriptPubKey.  Sounds like someone is being too technical and requiring too much college (as you put it).

The question is, how did you generate or create the address?  There are two halves to an address.

1. The address itself, and analogous to a PO Box. It's fairly anonymous, and secure.  You can deliver to it...  but can only take things out of it if you have a private key.
2. The private key (not to be confused with ScriptPubKey).  This is a secret to be protected.

I have never used ZipZap, so they will either ask you for an address to send coins to, or they will give you a voucher at Mt Gox.

You'll need to give us more information about how you purchased the coins, or contact ZipZap themselves.

Comment: Hey, thanks for holding my hand through this. I am more and more feeling that I got ripped off, but am quite curious as to how it happened so I don't get caught a second time.  I do have the voucher.  I will upload it soon, I have a kitten who thinks the keyboard is the best place to sit, and he is in mylap waiting to pounce at the cursor.

Comment: The voucher has a receive code, Don't have any idea what that is, The account number where the money was sent, and the amount.  When I go to zipzapinc.com and look up the transaction, I find the date and time paid. Then, I go to the bitcoin block explorer, plug in the date and time, and locate the block that contains the transaction, in this case https://blockexplorer.com/tx/d6be34ccf6edddc3cf69842dce99fe503bf632ba2c2adb0f95c63f6706ae0c52#o1.

Comment: @eanx - What other companies are mentioned on the voucher? Any URL?  BitInstant and ZipZap have a Bitcoin agreement. Have you tried contacting ZipZap support?

Comment: Try contacting support at support@zipzapinc.com.